# Updated iPhone app not overwriting old version -- why?

Tags: iphone, version, icons

When we create a new version of one of our iPhone apps and load it to a device, it shows up as an *additional* icon instead of replacing/overwriting the old one.  Touching the old icon brings up the old version and touching the new icon brings up the new one.  This is using ad hoc versions on a debug device -- we have not submitted the update to Apple yet.

We have not had this problem with other apps -- just this one.  I suspect the problem involves certificates, OS requirements, or something in the application's default plist.

I can share more information if needed, but I'm not sure which info is relevant.  Does this ring any bells with anyone?

Comment: The problem seems to have gone away, so it was probably just a configuration problem.  Sorry I wasted anyone's time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are your application identifiers the same? They should be identical.

Comment: That may well be the issue.  Is it the Bundle Identifier you refer to?

Comment: Yep, that's the one. Target Settings > Properties > Identifier.

Comment: The bundle identifier can never change throughout the lifecycle of the app.

Comment: Seems to be the same.  Would it matter if the Display Name is changed?

Comment: no, it should only key off of the bundle ID. Have you tried copy-and-pasting old-to-new? Just to make sure you haven't mistyped a character.